# Extension Methods and Duck Typing

Tags: f#, extension-methods, duck-typing

Why do I get an error when trying to call `transform` on an string?

```
type Truck = Truck 
type Car = Car

type Vehicle<'a> =
    | TruckWrapper of Truck * 'a
    | CarWrapper of Car * 'a 

type Truck with
    member this.transform (x) = TruckWrapper(this, x)

type Car with
     member this.transform (x) = CarWrapper(this, x)

type System.String with 
    member this.transform (x) =
        match x with
        | "truck" -> TruckWrapper(Truck, this)
        | _ -> CarWrapper(Car, this)

let inline transform value x = (^T : (member transform : 'a -> Vehicle<'b>) (value, x))

let a = transform Truck 1
let b = transform Car (1, 2)
let c = transform "truck" 0
```

this will yield the following error

```
let c = transform "truck" 0
------------------^^^^^^^

stdin(77,19): error FS0001: The type 'string' does not support the operator 'transform'
```

whereas

```
let d = "vehicle".transform("truck")
```

works pretty fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, extension members are not usable from member constraints. This could be implemented in the compiler, but I doubt it will be any time soon — as far as I can tell, member constraints are a low-priority feature for the F# team.

Edit: for your own types: what happens is that when you define a type extension in the same module as the type itself, then it is compiled into a normal method on your type. If you move the extension to another module, then it is truly compiled as an extension and you will see the same behavior as with `System.String`.

Comment: well, they are - at least for my own types.

Comment: shot! That is a real downer now. Thanks for your answer thou

Comment: I think is important to note that there is a way to work around this limitation by creating an intermediate type and an operator-like method call.

Comment: Hi Gustavo, can you explain in detail how you would solve this then?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not quite sure if the alternative Gustavo alludes to would work with your original code, since the String extension method has a different signature from your other `transform` methods, `member transform : x:string -> Vehicle<System.String>` vs. `member transform : x:'a -> Vehicle<'a`>` otherwise.

If they have all the same type, then it's something along the lines of:

```
type IntermediateVehicle = IntermediateVehicle with
    static member ($) (IntermediateVehicle, x : Truck) =
        fun value -> x.transform value
    static member ($) (IntermediateVehicle, x : Car) =
        fun value ->  x.transform value
    static member ($) (IntermediateVehicle, x : string) =
        fun value -> x.transform value

let inline transform value x = (IntermediateVehicle $ value) x

let a = transform Truck 1
let b = transform Car (1, 2)
let c = transform "truck" 0
// val a : Vehicle<int> = TruckWrapper (Truck,1)
// val b : Vehicle<int * int> = CarWrapper (Car,(1, 2))
// val c : Vehicle<int> = TruckWrapper (Truck,0)
```

Comment: great! thanks for this example. The next question already looming. It seems this whole thing just work with infix operators. For example if I define `static member toVehicle (IntermediateVehicle, x : Truck) = x.transform()` and the the inline function as `let inline transform value = IntermediateVehicle.toVehicle(value)` I get an error. Why? (I just left out the 2nd param)